# Need to extract all links from script tag HTML Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

Basically i need to parse all src="" links from all `<script>` tags in HTML.

`<script src="path/to/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Unfortunately, bs4 cannot do that. Any ideas how can i achieve this?

Comment: Of course bs4 can do it, which part of it are you lost on? Finding all script tags or extracting the src attribute?

Comment: On extracting the src. I've used next code ```python test = soup.find_all('script')
links = [link['src'] for link in test]``` and recieved an error ```python KeyError: 'src'``` This example worked fine with other tags

Comment: Meaning there is at least one script tag without a src attribute, probably has some inline javascript. Try `[link['src'] for link in test if 'src' in link]`

Comment: Error no more, but it returns an empty list

Comment: We'll need a look at the HTML. Can you provide a link?

Comment: OK, I don't know what the `in` operator is configured to do in bs4, but checking for containment within `.attrs` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4
text = requests.get('http://example.com').text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, features='html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
srcs = [link['src'] for link in scripts if 'src' in link.attrs]
print(srcs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would condense and use `script[src]` to ensure script has src attribute

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('http://example.com').content
soup = bs(r, 'lxml') # 'html.parser' if lxml not installed
srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select('script[src]')]
```